# when install torch7, fatal error: errno.h: No such file or directory

Tags: git, macos, lua, torch

install torch following http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html

system version: mac ox sierra 10.12

after git clone and cd ~/torch; bash install-deps;

Errors come:

./install.sh 
Prefix set to /Users/torch/install

Installing Lua version: LUAJIT21

Installing common Lua packages

env MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8 gcc -O2 -fPIC -I/Users/torch/install/include -c src/lfs.c -o src/lfs.o

src/lfs.c:36:19: fatal error: errno.h: No such file or directory

#include 
                   ^
compilation terminated.

Error: Build error: Failed compiling object src/lfs.o

after google, there is no correct solution.
any hints, help me, thank you!

Comment: Can you add -I /usr/include to your FLAGS? Does errno.h live there on OS X?

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-migrator/sdks/WatchSimulator.sdk/usr/include/sys/errno.h   Its here, add it into include folder, but it needs other .h file

Answer (score 0):

`xcode-select --install` fixed the problem